# randomize number (on a range) on css transform: translateX

Tags: css, animation, random, range

I have this animation, I would like to randomize the translateX value with a specific range.

```
#peperone{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 7;
    animation: droppepper 4s linear forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite ;
    }
  
    @keyframes droppepper{
        from { 
            transform: translateY(-400px) translateX(-90%) rotate(0deg);
        }

        to {
            transform : translateY(1000%) translateX(-30%) rotate(180deg);
        }
}
```

I saw a lot of answers here on stackoverflow and other pages as well, but I can't put it to work..
I tried with

```
.random(@min, @max) {
    @random: `Math.round(Math.random() * (@{max} - @{min}) + @{min})`;
}
```

and adding `.random(-100, -20);` into #peperone, but then I don't know how to use that number inside the transform translateX().

Is this doable or am I pretending too much? :P
If so, can you help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number with Javascript and update a set css variable, I included an example below.

```js
const randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 20 + 1) + 20)
console.log('translateX will animate to: ',randomInt*-1 + "%");

const root = document.documentElement;
root.style.setProperty('--random-int', randomInt*-1 + "%");

document.getElementById('guide').style.width = randomInt + "%";
document.getElementById('guide').textContent = randomInt + "%";
```

```css
:root {
  --random-int: -50%; 
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#peperone{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 7;
    animation: droppepper 4s linear forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    height: 100px;
}

#guide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes droppepper{
    from { 
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    to {
      transform: translateX(var(--random-int));
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="peperone"><div id="guide"></div></div>
```